# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE issue with updating + inserting

Tags: mysql, import

I am given a rather poorly structured table that has a Primary Key set to autoincrement and an UNIQUE key that is just unique. Conceptually, the UNIQUE key was supposed to be the primary key, but whoever made the table didn't have the UNQIUE key's column information at the time of the table's construction.

Now, we need to start doing regular update to this table where a provided text file contains updated rows and new rows. The challenge would be to replace the row if there's a matching value in the UNIQUE key and we actually don't care about the primary key itself as long as it autoincrements.

However, the way that LOAD DATA INFILE is structured is that it'd reset the PK we already have, which is bad - The reason we kept the PK is that it is foreign key to other legacy table (Sigh...).

So... is there a way I can make an elegant SQL-only update script that reads the updated table in text form and just updates based on the UNIQUE key column without screwing up the PK?

I guess a solution would be to export the table to tab form and do VLOOKUP to assign rows with the matching PK value (or NULL if it is a new row).

Any input?

Edit: Someone suggested that I do LOAD DATE INFILE into a temporary table and then do INSERT/UPDATE from there. Based on what [this post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/) and that post say, here's the script I propose:

```
// Create temporary table
CREATE TABLE tmp {
// my specifications
}

// Load into temporary table
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE *'[my tab file]'* 
REPLACE INTO TABLE *mytable* FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

// Set copy all the columns over except the PK column. This is for rows with existing UNIQUE values
UPDATE mytable
RIGHT JOIN tmp ON mytable.unique = tmp.unique
SET mytable.col1 = tmp.col1, ..., mytable.coln = tmp.coln, mytable.unique = tmp.unique;

// Now insert the rows with new UNIQUE values
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable (mytable.col1, mytable.col2, ...)
SELECT tmp.col1, tmp.col2, ... FROM tmp

// Delete the temporary table now.
DROP tmp;
```

Edit2: I updated the above query and tested it. It should work. Any opinions?

Comment: You have an sql-dump that you need to merge with a table, but you are unsure whether or not the dump has valid information?

Comment: The challenge would be to replace the row if there's a matching value in the UNIQUE - how is that a challenge? just see if you have the key in the table and put whatever you have from the file into the table! I can't quite understand your question.

Comment: That's because there is a legacy AUTO INCREMENT PK that is specific to the current DB. If I am importing a row with a matching UNIQUE key, it will alter the PK's value because the dump does not have that PK.

Answer (score 0):

You can load data into new table using LOAD DATA INFILE. Then use INSERT, UPDATE statements to change your table with data from new table, in this case you can link tables as you want - by primary/unique key or by any field(s).

Comment: Cool. I heard of this trick before. However, how do you do a table wide INSERT-UPDATE on the basis of a specified column? I can do that in PHP, but would like to stick to MySQL only.

Comment: Actually, I got an idea see Edit in original post.